# Determine whether a variable has positive influence in Boolean function

Tags: complexity-theory, discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

Given a Boolean function $f$ over the set of variables $X =\{ x_1,...,x_n \}$, the influence of $x_i$ is defined as the probability that changing only $x_i$ on random input changes $f$.
Given a function $f$ presented in $\text{CNF}$, and a coordinate, are there any known methods for determine if the coordinate has positive influence?

Comment: Finding all shortest implicates may deal with it.

Comment: A variable $x_i$ has zero influence if and only if the function doesn't depend on the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a CNF $\phi$ and a variable $x_i$, deciding whether $\phi$ depends on $x_i$ is NP-complete. It is clearly in NP: all we need to verify that $\phi$ depends on $x_i$ is two inputs different on $x_i$ on which $\phi$ evaluates to different values.

In the other direction, we reduce from SAT. Given a CNF $\psi = C_1 \land \cdots \land C_m$, let $x$ be a new variable and consider the CNF $\phi = \psi \land x$. If $\psi$ is satisfiable then $\phi$ depends on $x$, since substituting such a satisfying assignment reduces $\phi$ to $x$. If $\psi$ is not satisfiable then $\phi$ is always false, and in particular doesn't depend on $x$.

Comment: Well, this also gives a hint how to reduce it to SAT. Just make a formula $(\varphi\land x_i)\oplus(\varphi\land\overline{x_i})$.

Comment: Can I ask a somewhat tangential question? I understand "depend on x_i" to mean that $\exists z: \phi(z) \neq \phi(z^i)$, where $z^i$ is $z$ with the $i$th bit flipped. My question is this: if you represent $\phi$ as a multilinear polynomial in $x_1, ..., x_n$ then does $\phi$ depend on all the variables that occur in this polynomial expansion?

Comment: Yes. This is a nice exercise.